# OpenID login authentication fails with 'access_denied' error

Tags: authentication, owin, openid

I have a problem when trying to login to a web site I'm working on. The issue occurs occationally with several users and since it doesn't happen every time it is hard to reproduce. The issue is solved by clearing cookies and cache.

I was able to catch a log and I see this errors:

"OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error: 'access_denied'. Error_Description (may be empty): 'Policy evaluation failed for this request, please check the policy configurations.'. Error_Uri (may be empty): ''."

...\Auth\SameSiteCookieMiddleware.cs:line 42:

```
 public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(loginPath))
        {
            context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(
                x => SetPolicyOnSetCookieHeader(context.Response),
                null);
        }

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }

 private void SetPolicyOnSetCookieHeader(IOwinResponse response)
    {
        if (!response.Headers.ContainsKey(SetCookieHeader))
        {
            return;
        }

        var cookieValues = response.Headers.GetValues(SetCookieHeader);

        var updatedValues = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        foreach (var v in cookieValues)
        {
            //fix nonsecure SameSite=None auth cookies
            string cookieHeader = v.ToString();
            if (v.StartsWith("OpenId"))
            {
                if (v.Contains("SameSite=None"))
                {
                    cookieHeader = cookieHeader.Replace("; SameSite=None", "");
                }
            }
            if (isCookieSecured)
            {
                if (!(v.Contains("Secure") || v.Contains("secure")))
                {
                    cookieHeader = cookieHeader.ToString() + "; Secure";
                }
            }
            updatedValues.Add(cookieHeader);
        }
        response.Headers.SetValues(SetCookieHeader, updatedValues.ToArray());
    }
```

I wasn't able to find information about this error. Any ideas?

Search on several pages including stackoverflow.